# Android Datagram Sockets not working

Tags: android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am trying to implement basic Datagram Sockets in Android. I am starting with one of the samples available on the web:

```
String messageStr="Hello Android!";
int server_port = 54372;
try {
  DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
  InetAddress local = null;
  local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.127");
  int msg_length=messageStr.length();
  byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
  DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local, server_port);
  s.send(p);
} catch (SocketException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have enables the INTERNET permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The program dies when it hits the `s.send(p)` command.

What am I missing? It must be something obvious.

Comment: you should post the message from your logcat that happens when it  'dies'

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error which you are not catch-ing: NetworkOnMainThreadException.
You should do all networking staff in another Thread or AsyncTask.

For example:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        UDPSend();
    }

    void UDPSend()
    {
        String messageStr = "Hello Android!";
        int server_port = 54372;
        try
        {
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress local = null;
            local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.57");
            int msg_length = messageStr.length();
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local, server_port);
            s.send(p);
            android.util.Log.w("UDP", "Works fine!");
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            android.util.Log.w("UDP", "Catched here.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

To execute the thread in your main thread: `new MyThread().start();`

UPDATE:

UDP receiver in an Asynctask:
This is a real example of an app. I've removed some lines which are not relevant.
I show you the doInBackgroud, the one that receive the UDP packets.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... urls)
{
    DatagramSocket socketUDP;

    try
    {
        socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(5050);
        socketUDP.setSoTimeout(5000);

        // set it to true if you want to receive broadcast packets
        socketUDP.setBroadcast(false); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    byte[] buff = new byte[512];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);
    try
    {
        asyncTask_UDP_is_running=true;
        // Keep running until application gets inactive
        while (aplicationActive)
        {
            try
            {
                socketUDP.receive(packet);
                android.util.Log.w("UDP", "got a packet");
            }
            catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException ex)
            {
                // timeout
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null; 
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        asyncTask_UDP_is_running=false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: I am already doing that. I just included the snippet of code that seemed relevant.

Comment: @DanDickerson Then it should work, it does for me. I just copy your code into my workspace change the IP to my IP network and run it in the UI, it fired an exception, I put it in a `Thread` and works fine. Maybe it's the IP, try to use the loopback IP `127.0.0.1` to see if it works.

Comment: I finally got it work with your suggestions. Can you now help me get the listener to work? I tried setting up another class, GetThread, that was similar to your example, but it doesn't seem to actually receive the UDP messages.

Comment: @DanDickerson: If you are using the emulator to receive UDP packets, plese, do a search in this site for something like "Emulator receive UDP packet". There are some ports you need to redirect.

Comment: No, I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3.

Comment: @DanDickerson: See my updated answer for an example of a UDP receiver.